# DialogFragment remove transparent black

Tags: android, dialog

I need to create a DialogFragment without the transparent black layer in the background, or at least swap it with a transparent white one.

Tried to use this trick from a different SO answer, but it's not what I looking for:
`getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));`

As you can see on this image, there is a red area around the dialog, but it's not the one I looking for, there must be an other background:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4hlgil6btxtqcg4/dialog.png

If you have any idea, or workaround, please share with me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

you have to set `android:windowIsFloating` to false and `android:windowBackground` to your custom color in the dialog style:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**TestDialogFragment**

```
public class TestDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyDialog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set it to the color transparent:

```
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Or create your own custom layout to your dialog, here it is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/).

Comment: You can use some symply - setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)